# I am confused, is $\{[a,b], \phi\}$ a topological space based on the definition of the open set?

Tags: general-topology

From the definition based on neighbourhood, I know the interval $[a,b]$ is not belong to a topological space, as the end points have no neighbourhoods;

However, I can not judge it based on the definition of open sets, seems that for $X=[a,b]$, the collections $\{[a,b], \phi\}$ do obey the axioms:

1. The (trivial) subsets $X$ and the empty set emptyset are in $T$.
2. Whenever sets $A$ and $B$ are in $T$, then so is $A$ intersection $B$.
3. Whenever two or more sets are in $T$, then so is their union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of neighborhood you are using is based on the standard topology of $\Bbb R$. However this is far from the only topology on $\Bbb R$. For example, in the discrete topology, every sunset of $\Bbb R$ is open.

Comment: Thank you! To make sure, so u means that in the discrete topology of $\Bbb R$, I can choose a closed interval [a,b] as the subset, and still call it the open set?

Comment: Yes. Any particular set in $\Bbb R$ can be open depending on the topology.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am confused here, because for the neighborhood, the 'open' has the actual meaning, because it has no boundary; I dont actually know what the actual meaning of 'open' in the definition based open sets. Seems that nothing is really have boundary. @ Tim Raczkowski

Comment: The word open can be misleading here.  It originated, in the sense of having no boundary, from the standard topology.  In general, the term open is an abstraction.  A topology is any systems of subsets which satisfy the axioms you have stated.  Any member of the topology is referred as open.  When the word open is used in this sense, it has nothing to do with boundaries per se.

Comment: I get it, it really helps! Thank you! @Tim Raczkowski

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a topology, you can define any open sets you want, as long as you satisfy the axioms you quote.  It looks like you want $\{[a,b],\phi \}$ to be the set of open sets.  In this case you have the only topology on a one-point set.  You have only one point, which is $[a,b]$, which you have told us is open.  As the axioms you quote require the universe to be open, and $[a,b]$ is the universe, it better be open, which it is.

Comment: Thank you! I still dont get the meaning of 'open' here. I can understand $[a,b]$ is a point, but how can I understand it is the open universe?

Answer (score 0):

The topology is defined formally in terms of open sets. 
You can show that the open sets defined in R as the sets generated
by the open intervals (x,y), that is a set G is open if every point is
contained in some open interval and that interval is fully contained in G.

Now take the topology on [a,b] to be those sets intersected with [a,b].
You can confirm that the rules for a topology are still satisfied, even though you will have sets like [a,z) and (z,b] which would not be open in R but are certainly open in [a,b].  Similarly, [a,b] is open in [a,b] but would not be open in R.

It all depends on the topology you choose for your space, as long as the formal rules (intersection,union and X,empty ) are satisfied, that is a valid
topology

Comment: Thank you! I dont get the point [a,b] is not open in R. Let's discuss the topology of R, and seems that {R,ϕ,[a,b]} also give a topology: [a,b] is the subset of R, and we have the intersection between [a,b] and R is [a,b]; the union of them is R. Seem the rule is satisfied?@david

Comment: [a,b] is not open in R with the standard topology since a and b would not have proper open neighbourhoods.

Comment: [a,b] is not open in R with the standard topology since a and b would not have proper open neighborhoods.  {R,ϕ,[a,b]} defines a completely different (& unrelated) topology on R, you can verify the axioms are satisfied with the open sets being R, ϕ,[a,b].  In this topology [a,b] is open in R.  Whether a set is open or not depends  on whether you can 'match' it to one of the axioms for the topology, rather than the underlying universal set.   Also, [a,b] is not a point, it is a set. "open" is a property of sets, not points, it makes no sense to talk about points being open or not open.

Comment: It make sense. Thank you! @david